Nvidia driver lets internal graphic card work, but not configure it
I have Ubuntu 24.04 on an ASUS Z8NA-D6 motherboard, with:

External graphics card NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2070] with driver 560.35.03
Internal graphics card Aspeed AST2050 with 8MB VRAM with last manufacturer´s drivers.

I want to be able to use the internal card for display and choose if I want to use the external one only for computing or also for display. But right now the internal card can´t be configured, is a "Schrödinger card", alive and dead at the same time.

Upon starting, booting messages display in the #external# card

When I select "Ubuntu" in grub, after a while the display switches to the #internal# card and shows a small text with animated red/white dots on violet background: Ubuntu 24.04 . . . .

After a while it switches back to the #external card#.



An error message flashes by: "Could not switch the monitor configuration. could not set the configuration for CRTC 497"
Then it shows the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS login screen


If I login to "Ubuntu on Xorg", the desktop only shows on the #external card#, the #internal# is ON, but black.

In the Displays settings I can only see the rectangle for the monitor on the #external card# as (1).
Below I also see the name of the two monitors. I can enter and manipulate the settings of the external one (2): change resolution etc. but "Apply" won´t work and it says "Changes Cannot be Applied - This could be due to hardware Limitations".

Ctrl-Alt F1 to F6 shows tty1-6 in #internal card#.
Ctrl-Alt F7 shows the desktop in the #external card#
Ctrl-Alt F8 to F12 shows blank screen in both monitors with a flashing white cursor in #internal card#


If I log out and login in Wailand is the same except:


In the Displays settings I see the rectangles for both monitors:

(1) on the #external card# and
(2) on the #internal#.



I can move them around and click "Apply", but nothing happens.
Below I also see the name of the two monitors. I can enter and manipulate the settings of the external one (2): change resolution etc. and "Apply", but the internal monitor doesn´t show any change.

Ctrl-Alt FX work the same, except F7 and F8 swap behaviours.

In the Terminal:

prime-select query -> on-demand


sudo prime-select intel -> Error: no integrated GPU detected

Last Nvidia driver was installed from the terminal with sudo ubuntu-drivers install auto.
I also tried installing the Nouveau driver from the "Additional
Drivers" in Software & Updates and rebooting.
In this case the "Ubuntu 24.04 . . . ." appears on both monitors, and if I login in Wayland I can move and see the white cursor moving in the internal card monitor, but nothing else: I don´t see the wall paper, I can´t see a window if I drag it inside... The cursor seems to change shape depending on what is below it, but everything else except the cursor is black.
I have dual boot Windows 10 Pro and all works OK there so it doesn´t seem related to BIOS or hardware.

I haven´t found a way to use the internal graphics card Aspeed AST205 with Ubuntu 24.04. I didn't find or guess any solution.
In case that helps someone in the same situation, the only work around I found was to install Ubuntu 22.0.4 instead.

Can you expand this answer to explain how it answers the question, which was about using the Internal graphics card Aspeed AST205 with Ubuntu 24.04, rather than Ubuntu 22.0.4.
